# How to manage too much rows in mysql (Growing 100k - 300k + per day)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, bigdata

I use MySQL as my primary database for my tracking software.

Tracking is standalone module in my app and I track `users` and `user_events` .

In `users` table I save each unique user which visits website and in `user_events` table I save events of that users. (one to many relation)

I have implemented that tracker in dozen of sites with medium to large traffic and going to add more sites, but problem is that `users` and `user_events` table is growing too much rate (currently I have ~9M `users` and ~15M rows in `user_events` table) So, my queries is slowing down time by time.

How can I organize tables, that I can save as much rows as I can and not to destroy query performance? Can anyone suggest anything?

Should I use alternative sql databases for such apps? or event nosql databases?

Comment: You may consider keeping the latest data in MySQL but migrate it somewhere else for older data (such as a NoSQL option).

Comment: Thank you. I have thought about that, but problem is if I archive data in NoSQL, then that database will grow too much and I will have same problem

Comment: Use partitions in the table, create appropriate indexes. Normalize the data in a proper way. This would help to reduce performance outrage

Comment: You have to think migrating to another databases that could be designed to handle a large amount of data like your case, try Google BigQuery or Redshift product of amazon

Comment: Does BigQuery or Redshift has good select performance?

Comment: If your data is not structured correctly then moving to a different DBMS is not going to help your query performance; also throwing more horsepower at a query is not a long-term solution. You need to follow @jimmacaulay’s suggestions. Also, updating your question with the table structures and some representative queries with their corresponding explain plans would be helpful

Comment: 10GB/year -- This is feasible in today's hardware; is it a problem?  Will you be "purging" old data after, say, 90 days?  If purging I want to push for a different solution.

Comment: Queries are slowing down -- There may well be fixes for such -- but fixing the queries and/or adding composite indexes and/or building and maintaining summary tables.  _We need to see the queries._